# why long click on PullToRefreshListView don't work?

Tags: java, android

I have a PullToRefreshListView - https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

I need to do a long click. My Code:

```
pullToRefreshView = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh_listview);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
    pullToRefreshView.setAdapter(adapter);
    pullToRefreshView.setLongClickable(true);
pullToRefreshView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Log.d("privet ia long click", "yes");
            return true;
        }
   });
```

But it don't work. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Check Example Given Along With This library and also check following code (This Code is From example code of this library only):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pulltorefresh);

    mPullRefreshListView = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.pull_refresh_list);

    // Set a listener to be invoked when the list should be refreshed.
    mPullRefreshListView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
            String label = DateUtils.formatDateTime(getApplicationContext(), System.currentTimeMillis(),
                    DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);

            // Update the LastUpdatedLabel
            refreshView.getLoadingLayoutProxy().setLastUpdatedLabel(label);

            // Do work to refresh the list here.
            new GetDataTask().execute();
        }
    });
    // Add an end-of-list listener
    mPullRefreshListView.setOnLastItemVisibleListener(new OnLastItemVisibleListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLastItemVisible() {
            Toast.makeText(PullToRefresh.this, "End of List!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    ListView actualListView = mPullRefreshListView.getRefreshableView();

    // Need to use the Actual ListView when registering for Context Menu
    registerForContextMenu(actualListView);

    mListItems = new LinkedList<String>();
    mListItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(mStrings));

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListItems);

    /**
     * Add Sound Event Listener
     */
    SoundPullEventListener<ListView> soundListener = new SoundPullEventListener<ListView>(this);
    soundListener.addSoundEvent(State.PULL_TO_REFRESH, R.raw.pull_event);
    soundListener.addSoundEvent(State.RESET, R.raw.reset_sound);
    soundListener.addSoundEvent(State.REFRESHING, R.raw.refreshing_sound);
    mPullRefreshListView.setOnPullEventListener(soundListener);

    // You can also just use setListAdapter(mAdapter) or
    // mPullRefreshListView.setAdapter(mAdapter)
    actualListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

In above code list is used as following

```
ListView actualListView = mPullRefreshListView.getRefreshableView();
```

So after implimenting this you can use longpresslistener on it..

```
actualListView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Log.d("privet ia long click", "yes");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Hope it help and you got it...Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and saved it .

first I use this code but no work.

```
mPullRefreshListView.getRefreshableView().setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    return true;
}
```

});

because long click method is the View's method, when you long click your listview item that you just long click your listview item views,you need set the long click listener to the item view in your adapter. jsut like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if (convertView == null) {
  holder = new ViewHolder();
  convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.article_list_item, parent, false);
  //your long click is here.  
  convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
      return false;
    }
  });

return convertView;
```

}